# C# blockade regarding user input

Tags: c#

I'm quite a novice in C# due to not using it for many years now, but I'm having trouble with this one user input entity.

I'm wanting to receive userinput from a user when they use a certain command, and then add their input to the end of the associated link with the command. For example:

```
commands.CreateCommand("highscores + Input")
        .Do(async (e) =>
        {
            await 
e.Channel.SendMessage("https://www.example.org/highscores/user/Inputgoeshere");
```

So if they do !highscores + vessel, the result will be https://www.example.org/highscores/user/Vessel.

Comment: If highscores and Input are a variable then it should be (highscores + Input) with no double quotes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean as to variable. Neither highscore nor input are classified because I don't see the need unless I have to use a Console.ReadLine() to implement their input to the end of the highscores link.